# Множестванная фильтрация таблицы JS

Tags: javascript, html, фильтрация

Нужна помощь.

Имеется таблица, и 3 input по которым нужно отфильтровать строки.

При этом фильтра связаны, то есть если в первом input есть значение, ввод следующего работает с отфильтрованным результатом первого и т.д.(надеюсь понятно говорю)

На каждый input по колонке.
Как добиться того, чтобы была множественная фильтрация всей таблицы по определенным колонкам????

То что сделал на данный момент с JS

```
function searchColumns() {

        var inputReason, inputGroup, inputResponsible, filterReason, filterGroup, filterResponsible, found, table, tr, td, i, j, tdValue;

        inputReason = document.getElementById("searchInputReason");
        inputGroup = document.getElementById("searchInputGroup");
        inputResponsible = document.getElementById("searchInputResponsible");

        filterReason = inputReason.value.toUpperCase();
        filterGroup = inputGroup.value.toUpperCase();
        filterResponsible = inputResponsible.value.toUpperCase();

        let filters = [
            {
                name: 'reason',
                value: filterReason
            },

            {
                name: 'group',
                value: filterGroup
            },

            {
                name: 'responsible',
                value: filterResponsible
            }
        ];

        table = document.getElementById("searchTable");

        tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");


        for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {

            td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td");



            for (j = 0; j < td.length; j++) {
                // считываем все что есть в td как сроку в tdValue
                var tdValue = td[j].innerHTML.toUpperCase();
                // предполагаем что в этом td есть выпадашка(и), берем первую попавшуюся
                var dropdown = td[j].getElementsByTagName('select')[0];
                // если в этом td реально была выпадашка, то перезаписываем tdValue
                if (typeof(dropdown) !== "undefined") {
                // значение берем из options по ключу полученному из dropdown.selectedIndex
                    tdValue = dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].value.toUpperCase();
                }
                // проверка на совпадение фильтра и tdValue
                if (tdValue.indexOf(filterReason) > -1) {
                    found = true;
                }
            }

            if (found) {
                tr[i].style.display = "";
                found = false;
            } else {
                tr[i].style.display = "none";
            }
        }
    }
```

И пример структуры таблицы с которой я работаю.

```
<table class="table table-75">
        <!-- Header -->
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>№</th>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Branch</th>
            <th class="nowrap">BS</th>
            <th>Standard</th>
            <th>Total </th>
            <th>W15</th>
            <th>% W15</th>
            <th>W16</th>
            <th>% W16</th>
            <th>W17</th>
            <th>% W17</th>
            <th> <input style="width: 100px;" id="searchInputReason" onkeyup="searchColumns()" type="text" placeholder="Reason.."></th>
            <th>Comment</th>
            <th>Action </th>
            <th> <input style="width: 100px;" id="searchInputGroup" onkeyup="searchColumns()" type="text" placeholder="Group.."></th>
            <th> <input style="width: 100px;" id="searchInputResponsible" onkeyup="searchColumns()" type="text" placeholder="Responsible.."></th>
            <th>Deadline</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
        <!-- Body -->
        <tbody id="searchTable">
        <form name="form" id="form" class="form-inline" action="/report/sc_analysis/write" method="post"></form>
            <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="149">
            <input type="hidden" name="period" value="2020-04-20">
            <input type="hidden" name="branch_id" value="33">
            <tr>
                <td> 1</td>
                <td class="nowrap">2020-04-20 </td>
                <td class="nowrap">Barnaul </td>
                <td> <a class="horizontal-menu" href="/report/sc_analysis/cells/all/33/2020-04-20/41627"> 41627 </a> </td>
                <td> 3 </td>
                <td> 6 </td>
                <td> 3628800 </td>
                <td> 4,97 </td>
                <td> 3628800 </td>
                <td> 5,43 </td>
                <td> 3628800 </td>
                <td> 6,25 </td>
                <td>
                    <select name="reason[Barnaul_41627_3]" id="selectBarnaul_41627_3">
                        <option value="Правка в Глобус" selected="">Правка в Глобус</option>
                        <option value="Нулевой">Нулевой</option>
                         <option value="Оперативный">Оперативный</option>
                        <option value="Планирование">Планирование</option>
                        <option value="Правка в Глобус">Правка в Глобус</option>
                        <option value="Правка в NRI">Правка в NRI</option>
                        <option value="Правка в NIS">Правка в NIS</option>
                        <option value="Проблемная">Проблемная</option>
                        <option value="РИЧ">РИЧ</option>
                        <option value="СГОН">СГОН</option>
                        <option value="LTЕ сбой">LTЕ сбой</option>
                        <option value="Доп. анализ">Доп. анализ</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <textarea style="width: 250px;" title="C 21.04 TT №: 21643085 на Глобусе, добавлена зависимость до 30.06.2020 с внешней системой " almi",="" номер="" glbs-851."="" rows="1" name="comment[Barnaul_41627_3]">C 21.04 TT №: 21643085 на Глобусе, добавлена зависимость до 30.06.2020 с внешней системой "ALMI", номер glbs-851.</textarea>
                </td>

                <td>
                    <textarea style="width: 250px;" rows="1" name="action[Barnaul_41627_3]"></textarea>
                </td>

                <td>
                    <input style="width: 100px;" type="text" name="responsible_group[Barnaul_41627_3]">
                </td>

                <td>
                    <input style="width: 100px;" type="text" name="responsible[Barnaul_41627_3]">
                </td>

                <td>
                    <input type="date" name="deadline[Barnaul_41627_3]">
                </td>


                </tr>

        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: лучше какую-нибудь готовую бы взял, и просто объедок свой закинул туда..

Comment: @Vadim какую например?

Comment: @PavelOsetrov гугли, https://bootstrap-table.com/ я обычно вот эту использую, в твоё тз не вчитывался, ибо лень :)